# Subset of dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have about 20,000 unique identifiers in a column in one dataframe. I want to filter the data from a second, larger dataframe (about 180,000 rows) so that only the rows with matching identifiers are left.

So, dataframe 1 looks something like this

```
    df1 <- c("identifierab1","identifier56gh","identifier4znvh2")
```

dataframe 2 has 72 columns but one of the columns also has identifiers

```
    df2$relevantcolumn <- c("identifierab1", "identifierab1", "identifier9472bh")
```

Ultimately, I want to filter df2 so that the only rows left are the rows in which `df2$relevantcolumn` matches the values in `df1`. I have tried `%in%` and `matches` but nothing seems to work..

Comment: Did you try `subset(df2, relevantcolumn %in% df1)` Or `subset(df2, relevantcolumn %in% df1$relevant_column)` ?

Comment: `df2[df2$relevantcolumn %in% df1]` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it says '<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)' but I know there are matches in there

Comment: Maybe there are whitespaces there. Try to wrap it in `trimws`, so `subset(df2, trimws(relevantcolumn) %in% trimws(df1))`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there were whitespaces in the data hence it didn't match. We can use `trimws` to remove the whitespace and then try to subset it.

```
df2[trimws(df2$relevantcolumn) %in% trimws(df1), ]
```

Or if `df1` is dataframe

```
df2[trimws(df2$relevantcolumn) %in% trimws(df1$relevant_column), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `grep`

```
df2[grep(paste(df1, collapse="|"), df2$relevantcolumn),]
```